# How to One Hot Encode in python for numerical?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Im new to python and trying to understand how to use scikitlearn

I have a dataframe:

```
         Id        ServiceSubCodeKey  ...         Aim   PrintDate
0        1895650                  2  ...          NaN  2018-07-27
1        1895650                  4  ...          NaN  2018-08-13
2        1896355                  2  ...          NaN  2018-08-10
3        1897675                  9  ...         12.0  2018-08-13
4        1897843                  2  ...          NaN  2018-08-10
         ...                ...  ...          ...         ...
3940510  2178737                 3  ...          1.0  2019-06-14
3940511  2178737                 4  ...          1.0  2019-06-14
3940512  2178737                 7  ...          1.0  2019-06-14
3940513  2178737                 1  ...          1.0  2019-06-14
3940514  2178750                 6  ...          4.0  2019-06-14
```

I am trying to hot encode 3 million rows on the basis of id vs servicesubcodekey such that the final One hot encoding looks like:

```
           id   ServiceSubCodeKey  ...           Encoding   PrintDate
0        1895650                  2  ...          0101          2018-07-27
1        1895650                  4  ...          0101          2018-08-13
2        1896355                  2  ...          01          2018-08-10
3        1897675                  9  ...          000000001   2018-08-13
4        1897843                  2  ...          01          2018-08-10
         ...                ...  ...          ...         ...
3940510  2178737                 3  ...          1011001         2019-06-14
3940511  2178737                 4  ...          1011001         2019-06-14
3940512  2178737                 7  ...          1011001     2019-06-14
3940513  2178737                 1  ...          1011001     2019-06-14
3940514  2178750                 6  ...           000001      2019-06-14
```

So as you see for every id which has a service subcode there is a unique encoding and if the id is same then the encoding is the range of service subcode and it is turned on for the digits for example for id 18 if the max service subcode is 4 then encoding is 0101 since 2 and 4 exist for that id.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was able to generate an approach for this:

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import add
df = pd.DataFrame([
[1895650,2,float("nan"),  "2018-07-27"],
[1895650,4,float("nan"),  "2018-08-13"],
[1896355,2,float("nan"),  "2018-08-10"],
[1897675,9,12.0 ,"2018-08-13"],
[1897843,2,float("nan"),"2018-08-10"],
[2178737,3,1.0,  "2019-06-14"],
[2178737,4,1.0, "2019-06-14"],
[2178737,7,1.0 , "2019-06-14"],
[2178737,1,1.0 , "2019-06-14"],
[2178750,6,4.0 , "2019-06-14"]],columns = ["Id","ServiceSubCodeKey","Aim","PrintDate"])
```

First we one-hot-encode the categorical variable an put them together:

```
columns = pd.get_dummies(df["ServiceSubCodeKey"]).astype(str)
df2 = columns[1]
for col in columns.columns[1::]:
    df2 += columns[col]
```

Then we add them to our original dataset:

```
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
df3[1] = df3[1].apply(lambda x: list(map(int, list(x))))
```

We group our lists together and sum them:

```
df4 = df3[["Id",1]].groupby("Id").agg(lambda x: sum_l(x)).reset_index()
df4[1] = df4[1].apply(lambda x: sum_l2(x))
df4[1] = df4[1].apply(lambda x: f(x))
df4[1] = df4[1].apply(lambda x: ''.join(list(map(str, list(x)))))
```

And finally join them:

```
df5 = pd.merge(df,df4, on="Id", how="left")
df5

    Id      ServiceSubCodeKey   Aim     PrintDate   1
0   1895650 2                   NaN     2018-07-27  0101
1   1895650 4                   NaN     2018-08-13  0101
2   1896355 2                   NaN     2018-08-10  01
3   1897675 9                   12.0    2018-08-13  0000001
4   1897843 2                   NaN     2018-08-10  01
5   2178737 3                   1.0     2019-06-14  101101
6   2178737 4                   1.0     2019-06-14  101101
7   2178737 7                   1.0     2019-06-14  101101
8   2178737 1                   1.0     2019-06-14  101101
9   2178750 6                   4.0     2019-06-14  00001
```

We need also the functions below:

```
def sum_l(values):
    out = []
    for element in values:
        out.append(element)
    return out

def sum_l2(values):
    
    if type(values[0]) != int:
        out = values[0]
        for i in range(1,len(values)):
            out = list(map(add, out, values[i]))
    else:
        out = values
    return out

def f(x):
    while x[-1] == 0:
        x.pop()
    return x
```

Comment: Hi, im receiving a Memory error after I onehot code categorical variable step    vals1d = values.ravel()

MemoryError. Since I am dealing with 3million rows in my df, is there a way to error handle this?

Comment: Could you edit your question and explain the error in detail? It seems like either you have  too many values in `ServiceSubCodeKey` or that you need to process the dataset in slices and then join them rather that everything at once.

Comment: ok will do, but on this smaller sample ur solution works. But just one major issue is that, why does it show 0101000 three zeroes after for a id 1895650? the max subcodekey is 4. it should be 0101 and no more zeroes after that. do u have a fix for this? i will mark it correct @lets try

Comment: it is still giving the same output of 0101000 for id 189560. it should only show  0101. Also, notice for the last ID 2178750 where the ssc is 6, the encoding is wrongly placed at 0000100. It should just be 000001

Comment: Hey, I didn't edited the output last time...Check it now